# How to transform a Python tuple to a .csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, tuples

I would like to transform a Python tuple to a `.csv` file. Let's say I have a retrive() function and when I print it with `pprint` it looks like this:

```
test = tuple(retrive(directory))
pprint(test, width=1)
```

Then:

```
("opinion_1.txt, I am an amateur photographer and own three DSLR c.... purchase",
 "opinion_2.txt, This my second Sony Digital Came.... good camera for a good price!',
 'opinion_3.txt, \'I ordered this camera with high hopes after  couldn\\\'t find.\'')
```

So, I tried this with the `csv` module:

```
with open('/Users/user/Downloads/output.csv','w') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(['id','content'])
    for row in test:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

The problem is that I get a weird output which looks like this:

```
id,content
o,p,i,n,i,o,n,_,1,.,t,x,t,",", ,I, ,a,m, ,a,n, ,a,m,a,t,e,u,r, ,p,h,o,t,o,g,r,a,p,h,e,r, ,a,n,d, ,o,w,n, ,t,h,r,e,e, ,D,S,L,R, ,c,a,m,e,r,a,s, ,w,i,t,h, ,a, ,s,e,l,e,c,t,i,o,n, ,o,f, ,l,e,n,s,e,s,., ,H,o,w,e,v,e,r, ,t,h,a,t, ,c,o,l,l,e,c,t,i,o,n,
```

How can I get something like this:

```
opinion_1.txt,I am an amateur photographer and own three DSLR c.... purchase
opinion_2.txt,This my second Sony Digital Came.... good camera for a good price!
opinion_3.txt,I ordered this camera with high hopes after  couldn\\\'t find.
```

Comment: How does the string look like if there's a comma in the second part of the text? Also, the second string is opened with a double quote and ends with a single quote, what's up with that?

Comment: Thanks for the help @TimPietzcker, I did not understood you... could you provide a more detailed comment?.

Comment: Could there be more than one comma in a string, e. g. `"opinion_1.txt, I am an amateur photographer, I own three DSLR c.... purchase"`? If so, how would we know if the comma is in the filename or the descriptive text?

Comment: Ohh... thanks again @TimPietzcker, yes it can be a comma... However is there any way to change the separator to a less ambigous character like `|`?

Comment: Well, if `retrive()` were to return a tuple instead of a string, you wouldn't have to worry about the separator at all.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, nice observation. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSV trying to iterate over string you pass from the tuple. Change your code to:

```
for row in test:
    csv_out.writerow(row.split(', ', 1))
```

It means you split each string in the tuple by first occurrence of `', '`. 
It produces two elements for each row and it is what csv writer is need is.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `Pandas` solution, use `DataFrame constructor` and [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([ x.split(',') for x in test ])
df.columns = ["id","content"]
print df
#              id                                            content
#0  opinion_1.txt   I am an amateur photographer and own three DS...
#1  opinion_2.txt   This my second Sony Digital Came.... good cam...
#2  opinion_3.txt   'I ordered this camera with high hopes after ...

#for testing
#print df.to_csv(index=False)
df.to_csv("/Users/user/Downloads/output.csv", index=False)
#id,content
#opinion_1.txt, I am an amateur photographer and own three DSLR c.... purchase
#opinion_2.txt, This my second Sony Digital Came.... good camera for a good price!
#opinion_3.txt, 'I ordered this camera with hig
```

If there is multiple `,`, you can use `split` by first occurence of `,`:

```
import pandas as pd

test = ("opinion_1.txt,a","opinion_2.txt,b","opinion_3.txt,c",  "opinion_3.txt,b,c,k")
print test

print [ x.split(',', 1) for x in test ]
[['opinion_1.txt', 'a'], 
 ['opinion_2.txt', 'b'], 
 ['opinion_3.txt', 'c'], 
 ['opinion_3.txt', 'b,c,k']]

df = pd.DataFrame([ x.split(',', 1) for x in test ])
df.columns = ["id","content"]
print df
              id content
0  opinion_1.txt       a
1  opinion_2.txt       b
2  opinion_3.txt       c
3  opinion_3.txt   b,c,k

print df.to_csv(index=False)
id,content
opinion_1.txt,a
opinion_2.txt,b
opinion_3.txt,c
opinion_3.txt,"b,c,k"
```

Comment: This solution with pandas seems very interesting. However, I have this exception: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 23 elements, new values have 2 elements`. Any idea of what is happening?.

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing is destroyed if one of your sentences has multiple commas like this:

```
s = "opinion_4.txt, Oh my, what happens with really, really long sentences?"

>>> s.split(", ")
['opinion_4.txt',
 'Oh my',
 'what happens with really',
 'really long sentences?']
```

A better approach would be to find the *first* comma and then split the sentence using slicing at this location:

```
for line in text:
    comma_idx = line.find(', ')
    csvout.writerow(line[:comma_idx], line[comma_idx+2:])
```

For the sentence above, it would result in this:

```
('opinion_4.txt', 'Oh my, what happens with really, really long sentences?')
```